# Returning selected rows from a csv

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I'm using php(fgetcsv) in order to parse a csv file. The file is continuously updated and quite large. Is it possible to only return a selected number of rows(say the first 10 rows for example)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read data row wise and return whichever rows you want by keeping a track at current row number.

```
$pickedRows  = array(1, 3, 5);
$currentRow=0;
$theData = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            if(in_array(currentRow, $pickedRows))
                 $theData[] = $row;

            $currentRow++;

    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple while loop with your limit parameter `$rowlimit` will suffice

```
$rowlimit=10;
while ( ($fileinfo = fgetcsv($csvfil)) && ($rowlimit >= 0) )
{
//Your Statements
$rowlimit--;
}
```